# React Native: Android: Cannot generate signed APK

Tags: javascript, react-native

```
Execution failed for task ':app:packageRelease'.
Failed to read key my-key-alias from store
"/Users/MichaelLeung/GHRepos/MyApp/android/app/my-release-
key.keystore": Keystore was tampered with, or password was incorrect
```

I'm positive my password is correct; I've gone through the steps that Facebook lists on the React Native docs multiple times.

Comment: I think you have given wrong alias

Comment: I have the same problem. I provided all correct data tho! ://

Answer (score 3):

So if you were trying to generate a signed APK and used a no ASCII letter, you'd probably get this error.

Execution failed for task ':app:packageRelease'.

> com.android.ide.common.signing.KeytoolException: Failed to read key my-key-alias from store "/Users/.../.../.../android/app/my-release-key.keystore": 
>   keystore password was incorrect

I couldn't find a way to reset the old password.

Thankfully there is a work around, using the Android Studio.

First I had to remove all the code from gradle.properties and build.gradle,
(that I had to add according to the [docs.](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/signed-apk-android).

This solution is from a a comment here: [Keystore password was incorrect](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/8913)
"I am facing the same issue. Using Build -> Generate Signed APK in android studio works, but putting the config in build.gradle doesn't."

Then use the "signing/keytool UI that's part of Android Studio", which can be found in Build -> Generate Signed Bundle/APK ...

There you can create a new key store password and a key password WHICH HAVE TO BE THE SAME!!!

Note after finishing, Android Studio saves the app-release.apk file in android -> app -> release.

Happy coding :)

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem.
After hard coded the settings in the build.gradle, instead off set it in the gradle.properties, is was working.

```js
  signingConfigs {
    release {
        //if (project.hasProperty('MYAPP_RELEASE_STORE_FILE')) {
            storeFile file("key.keystore")
            storePassword "****"
            keyAlias "myKey"
            keyPassword "****"
       // }
    }
}
```

After further testing with java.lang.System.console(MYAPP_RELEASE_STORE_PASSWORD) I saw that there was a space after my password.

```js
  signingConfigs {
    release {            
        if (project.hasProperty('MYAPP_RELEASE_STORE_FILE')) {
        java.lang.System.console(MYAPP_RELEASE_STORE_PASSWORD)

            storeFile file(MYAPP_RELEASE_STORE_FILE)
            storePassword MYAPP_RELEASE_STORE_PASSWORD
            keyAlias MYAPP_RELEASE_KEY_ALIAS
            keyPassword MYAPP_RELEASE_KEY_PASSWORD
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried :

```
$ ./gradlew clean
$ ./gradlew bundleRelease
```

and it worked.

Answer (score -1):

I took help from Yoruba's answer, I was trying to build app left by another developer

I was trying to build keystore file using
 `keytool -genkey -v -keystore playnice.keystore -alias playnice -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 10000`
the command prompt then asks for password, and this password should be the same as set in build.gradle file.
In my case build.gradle file had Keys instead of password, thus I looked in gradle.properties to find value of that key

Answer (score -1):

Don't be confused! 
**It's actually a simple mistake**
put your password:
Not in

> Users/YourName/.gradle/gradle.properties

But in

> Users/YourName/.gradle/gradle.properties

I was trying to build based on a project-specific gradle.properties (i.e. at projectDir/android/gradle.properties), but a global gradle.properties I had configured during a previous project was being used instead. The fix for me was to delete my global gradle.properties (i.e Users/YourName/.gradle/gradle.properties)